# How do I evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} [\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{(n-1)^2} ]$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to evaluate this limit $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} [\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{(n-1)^2} ]$
It is the $\infty-$$\infty$ form. I've tried rewriting it as-

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} [(n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(n-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}]$
and then used the difference of squares formula. Apparantly that only made things worse. I'm stuck with the cube roots. I considered some form of rationalisation but to no avail. How should I approach this limit?

Comment: Pull out $n^{3/2}$ and use the fact that $(1+x)^{2/3}\sim 1+\frac 2  3x+o(x)$.

Comment: If the expression under limit is $A-B$ then $A/B\to 1$ and $A-B=\frac{(A/B) - 1}{(A/B)^3-1}\cdot\frac{A^3-B^3}{B^2}$. First fraction tends to $1/3$ and the second fraction is simpler to deal as $A^3-B^3=4n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Multiply and divide by the conjugate in order to obtain:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{(n + 1)^{2}} - \sqrt[3]{(n - 1)^{2}} & = \frac{(n + 1)^{2} - (n - 1)^{2}}{\sqrt[3]{(n + 1)^{4}} + \sqrt[3]{(n^{2} - 1)^{2}} + \sqrt[3]{(n - 1)^{4}}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Indeed. After simplifying the numerator and pulling out n^$\frac{4}{3}$ from the denominator, we see that it's degree is greater than the numerator and we get zero. That's the answer.